# Use Google Sheets API with current authenticated Cloud SDK user

Tags: google-sheets, google-api

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to connect to a private sheet on Google (shared to specific users), using the already authenticated user on the Google Cloud SDK (gcloud).

I understand it is possible to do so using a local service account json file (requiring to add the service account email to the sheet's shared settings) or using an API key (requiring public access to the sheet).

I have the Google Cloud SDK installed and have signed in to it (and already gone through the required OAuth sign in process for it).

I was hoping that I could re-use the gcloud credentials to connect to the sheets API but I keep getting permission denied issues.

Here's the simplified connection code (Node JS) for it, just standard sheets api basically.

```
        // const spreadsheetId = 'THE_ID_FOR_MY_SHEET'
        const range = 'test_data!A1:AA'
        const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
            scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
        });
        const client =  await auth.getClient();

        const sheets = google.sheets( {
                                        version: 'v4',
                                        auth: client
                                    } );

        const request = {
            spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
            range: range,
        };

        const res = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get( request )
            .catch( err => console.error('Error in sheets.spreadsheets.values.get' + err) )
```

As far as I can see from tracing through that code, `auth` does load the currently logged in user credential and issues the request to sheets using a `Authorization: Bearer ...` type authentication.

However this always results in permissions denied.

I have given the authenticated user's email to the share permissions on the sheet.

Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: Cloud authorization is not the same as Google apis authorization.    If you cant use the service account from cloud then your going to have to request authorization of the uer.

Comment: @DaImTo I understand that, but considering I've authenticated as user X in gcloud and would still authenticate as user X if I was to do a client-based OAuth scenario to authenticate to google sheets, is there a way I can re-use the current authenticated credential to obtain new credential for sheets without having to go through the whole OAuth client auth again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DaImTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto)'s comment is correct.

`gcloud` (Cloud SDK) is an [installed app](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app) it uses an OAuth Client ID (backed by a Google-managed Project) to authenticate User (and Service Account) credentials and provides auth'd access to Google services. The OAuth Client ID represents the `gcloud` app and its owner (Google).

Google's services use OAuth but depending on the service, you will be limited in the scenarios you can use. Google requires that services that access user data be authenticated using User credentials (e.g. your@gmail.com; your@work.email.com) by an OAuth Client ID that identifies the app (Google Project) that's mediating the request.

**Note:** There's an exception to the above. Google Workplace permits admins to use [Domain-wide Delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) using a Service Account to access users' data. This isn't available for consumer (e.g. your@gmail.com) accounts.

When you `gcloud auth login`, Google prompts you with a set of OAuth scopes that do not include e.g. Google Sheets. I assume that the Google-managed Project backing `gcloud` does not have the Sheets service enabled either.

When you write an app, just like the Google-developed `gcloud` app, you must create an OAuth Client ID to identify you(r business) in the form of a Google Project and the Project defines the services (e.g. Sheets) that are enabled within it. Your app (unlike `gcloud`) must also prompt the user for [Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#sheets) OAuth scopes.

When you use Google's client libraries, **if** you can authenticate using a Service Account, there's a useful facility called Application Default Credentials (ADCs) through which your code can [find credentials automatically](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production). This is the path that your code is following. You don't have a Service Account and so I assume this is why you're being denied. Because you're using Google Sheets that has User data the **only** way you could use a Service Account would be to use Domain-wide Delegation. You will need to use the installed app flow see this [example](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs)